# meaning of this context

Tags: discourse-context

This is from [a news article](https://www.npr.org/2023/05/03/1173723661/atlanta-shooting-police-updates-medical-building) :

> The shooting took place just two floors above him, he recounted.
>
> "We were on the ninth floor. So once everyone heard that the shooting
> had happened on the 11th floor, you can imagine that some of the folks
> in the room got a little nervous and tense," he said.
>
> Johnson said everyone kept calm and the medical staff in the office
> ushered people into a secure back room while they waited for police to
> arrive to escort them out.
>
> **The medical staff "didn't make the matter worse by making it seem like
> there was some imminent threat to our health," he said.**

The shooting incident took place in a medical office building.

I'm confused about the meaning of the last sentence of the quote.

Which does it mean? :

1. The medical staff made it seem like there was some imminent threat to our health in order not to make the matter worse.
2. The medical staff didn't make it seem like there was some imminent threat to our health in order not to make the matter worse.

If it means #2, shouldn't 'not' be added between 'by' and 'making'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended meaning is the second one, and it's correct the way it's written. The problem is how you're parsing the sentence. Everything after "didn't" is a single verb phrase, which I've marked with [brackets]:

> The medical staff didn't [make the matter worse by making it seem like there was some imminent threat to our health].

It's worth noting that the sentence is very awkward, but that's normal for a quote, rather than the journalist's own words. I stumbled several times while trying to read it.

Comment: Thank you very much.